# Related Documents in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6

Back in Visual Studio 6 I was able to add a "Related Document" to a project to quickly and easily open Word files I used for version history notes, etc. How do I do this in Visual Studio 2010 if this is available?

Comment: Thankyou, Freddo. I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use "Add->Existing Item".

Comment: Thanks for the reply - So will this file get added into the compiled exe/dll or just be in the solution folder and referenced?

Comment: By default, a Word document would be set to "Build Action" = "None", and "Copy" = "Do not copy". If you want it to be copied to the build output (maybe it's a Help file), you can change that to "Copy newer" or "Copy always".